# Keras backed taking the derivative of a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am making a neural network with two customized activation function. The first activation function is f(x) and the second one is derivative of f(x) with respect to f(x). Instead of taking the derivative by hand, which is for my real case very hard, how can I make Keras backend do it automatically?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import keras
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Activation
from keras import regularizers
from keras import backend as K

def custom_activation_f(x):
    return (K.sigmoid(x) *2-1 )

def custom_activation_fprime(x):
    deriv(x)= # take the derivative of custom_activation_f(x)
    return deriv(x)

x_train=np.random.uniform(low=-1,high=1,size=(200,2))

model=Sequential([
     Dense(20,input_shape=(2,)),
     Activation(custom_activation_f),
     Dense(2,),
     Activation(custom_activation_fprime)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(x_train,x_train,epochs=20,validation_split=0.1)
```

---

**Update**: after I received an answer from Pranit Kothari:, I changed the custom_activation_fprim part to the following:

```
def custom_activation_fprime(x):
    my_derivative= K.gradients(custom_activation_f, x)
    return my_derivative
```

Is this how I should use it? Here is the error:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
W1004 12:07:29.987481  2280 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:74: The name tf.get_default_graph is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph instead.

W1004 12:07:30.011625  2280 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:517: The name tf.placeholder is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.placeholder instead.

W1004 12:07:30.016886  2280 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:4138: The name tf.random_uniform is deprecated. Please use tf.random.uniform instead.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\r.jack\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py", line 558, in make_tensor_proto
    str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]
  File "C:\Users\r. jack\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py", line 558, in <listcomp>
    str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]
  File "C:\Users\r. jack\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\compat.py", line 65, in as_bytes
    (bytes_or_text,))
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got <function custom_activation_f at 0x000002896662C1E0>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/p/CE/mytest3.py", line 24, in <module>
    Activation(custom_activation_fprime)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 93, in __init__
    self.add(layer)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 181, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 457, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py", line 299, in call
    return self.activation(inputs)
  File "C:/p/CE/mytest3.py", line 15, in custom_activation_fprime
    my_derivative= K.gradients(custom_activation_f, x)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2757, in gradients
    return tf.gradients(loss, variables, colocate_gradients_with_ops=True)
  File "C:\Users\r. jack\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gradients_impl.py", line 158, in gradients
    unconnected_gradients)
  File "C:\Users\r. jack\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gradients_util.py", line 594, in _GradientsHelper
    ys = ops.convert_n_to_tensor_or_indexed_slices(ys, name="y")
  File "C:\Users\r. jack\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1456, in convert_n_to_tensor_or_indexed_slices
    values=values, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=False)
  File "C:\Users\r. jack\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1428, in internal_convert_n_to_tensor_or_indexed_slices
    value, dtype=dtype, name=n, as_ref=as_ref))
  File "C:\Users\r. jack\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1388, in internal_convert_to_tensor_or_indexed_slices
    value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "C:\Users\r. jack\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1224, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "C:\Users\r. jack\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 305, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\r. jack\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 246, in constant
    allow_broadcast=True)
  File "C:\Users\r. jack\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 284, in _constant_impl
    allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
  File "C:\Users\r. jack\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py", line 562, in make_tensor_proto
    "supported type." % (type(values), values))
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'function'> to Tensor. Contents: <function custom_activation_f at 0x000002896662C1E0>. Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can solve it.

1. Use K.gradients to take the derivative, but it requires tensor as input, but here it is a function. Below is the example snippet of how to use it.

   example code snippet

   ```
   def custom_activation_fprime(x):
       my_derivative= K.gradients(tf.convert_to_tensor(custom_activation_f(x), dtype=tf.float32), x)
       return my_derivative
   ```

or
2. Create a custom derivative function and pass that function as activation to the model

Comment: Thanks a lot. Don't we need to change custom_activation_f to custom_activation_f(x)?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `gradients` from keras?

```
from keras import backend
backend.gradients(loss, variable)
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please see my updated question? I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: Please provide Albert with a working answer, not just a piece of the solution.